# merge tags [dualhead] and [dual-monitor]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think [dual-monitor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dual-monitor) is probably better than [dualhead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dualhead).

Comment: I think we can do this manually, since there are only ~20.

Comment: Agreed, but I wanted at least a third endorsement, you know: look like I'm seeking consensus.